# regex underscore delimited pattern matching

Tags: regex

Hi I am struggling with getting the regex right for the pattern matching.

I basically want to use regex to match the following pattern.

```
[anyCharacters]_[anyCharacters]_[anyCharacters]_[anyCharacters]_[1or2]
```

for example, the below string should match to the above pattern.
AA_B_D_ test-adf123_1

i tried the below regex but doesn't work .....

```
^[.]+_[.]+_[.]+_[.]+_(1|2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
^(.+_)+(1|2)$
```

If you want to specify the number of occurrences:

```
^(.+_){4}(1|2)$
```

Comment: The `AA_B_D_ test-adf123_1` sample string has no `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 3):

`.` matches any character (once) `_` included

`.*` matches any character (largest sequence) (`_` included)

`[.]+` matches only `.` character (at least one) (largest sequence)

`[^_]+` matches any character except `_` (at least one) (largest sequence)

`.*?` matches any character (shortest sequence)

you may need one of the last two.

```
^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_(1|2)
```

or

```
^(.*?_){4}[12]
```

The problem with `.*?` is that it can backtrack and matches also

```
one_two_three_four_five_1
```

The shortest is

```
^([^_]+_){4}[12]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `[^_]` [*negated character class*](http://regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) rather than `[.]` that only matches a dot symbol:

```
^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[12]
```

If the pattern must match the whole string, add `$`:

```
^[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[^_]+_[12]$
```

Also, you may shorten it a bit with a [*limiting quantifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

```
^[^_]+(?:_[^_]+){3}_[12]$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ELjr1o/2).

Note that `[12]` is a better way to match single chars, it will match `1` or `2`. A grouping construct like `(...)` (or `(?:...)`, a non-capturing variant)
 should be used when matching  multicharacter values.

**Pattern details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `[^_]+`  - 1 or more chars other than `_`
- `(?:_[^_]+){3}`  - 3 occurrences of:

  - `_` - an underscore
  - `[^_]+` -  1 or more chars other than `_`
- `_` - an underscore
- `[12]` - `1` or `2`
- `$` - end of string.